# Optimal way to export JDK_HOME setting in openSUSE for use with PhpStorm?

Tags: linux, java, opensuse, sun-java6-jdk

I'm trying out PHPStorm on openSUSE, and it requires the Sun Java JDK which doesn't come by default.  I installed the Sun JDK based on directions [here](http://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/java-for-opensuse).

I can run PHPStorm file as `root` user after that procedure but when I try to run it under my user account I get an error saying that Java is not found.

The solution I'm using is to add the following to the top of the `phpstorm.sh` script:

`export JDK_HOME=/opt/java/64/jre1.6.0_30`

I'm wondering if this is the best way to accomplish this or if there is a better/cleaner way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to affect this export for all system (not a just for particular user) please create appropriate file-script in **/etc/profile.d** folder.

Example /etc/profile.d/java.sh

`export JDK_HOME=/opt/java/64/jre1.6.0_30`